# asp.net core dependency injection issue - AddScoped not creating a new instance

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I've been using asp.net core dependency injection and I have seen an not expected behavior, at least for me. I'm adding a new service to the container like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyClass>(provider =>
{
   return new MyClass(
      "anyValue"
   });
```

After that, I inject the class into another class to use it:

```
public class AnotherClass(IMyClass xxx){

}
```

The thing is that there are a couple configurations that are made on the MyClass constructor based on request information. The problem is that I've seen the MyClass constructor be executed at the application startup only. After that, the class seems to use the same instance for all calls. As I'm using Scoped service I'm expecting to have a new instance for each request, am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide an example please.

Comment: Make sure that `MyClass` isn't kept alive as [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: I believe I found out the issue but still don't know how to figure out. If I inject the IMyClass into the controller, the scoped life cycle works. If I inject it into another class (in my case, in another project), it seems to use singleton.

Answer (score 5):

Ok. The problem was that the class that was receiving the injection was added to the container as singleton. I just changed it to Scoped and everything worked well.

Thanks!